# Disabling a button block key events on firefox

Tags: javascript

I have a simple button. When the user click the button I want to disable the button and to register some key events.

Here is a simple example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button>Click me</button>
    <script>
        button = document.querySelector('button');
        button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            button.disabled = true;
            document.addEventListener('keydown', ()=>{
                alert('Key down')
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

On firefox when i run this code :

1. I load the page
2. I click the button
3. **I try to hit a key and nothing happens**
4. I cick anywhere on the page
5. I try again to hit a key and the alert box shows up

I don't understand why the user have to click somewhere on the page to "activate" the key events. This is not the case if i don't disable the button.

I've tried to give focus to another element. Like adding `document.body.focus();` to the click event and it doesn't helps.

P.S: This is a minimal example in pure js but in my project I'm using Vue.js to disable the button and to fire the click event (`<button @click='activateKeyEvents' :disabled='keyEventsAreActivated'`/>). So the ideal solution for me would be a solution that does not rely on the order in which I perform the tasks. Because in practice I have no control over this order.

Comment: It seems like in Firefox, after getting disabled, the Button remains `Active/Focused`. Whereas in Chrome, it automatically shifts the focus to body. So, try to `blur` the button in the event handler. Edit: Look at @nariman zaeim's answer, that's accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should remove focus from button too.

```
<button>Click me</button>
    <script>
        button = document.querySelector('button');
        button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            button.disabled = true;
            console.log('btn event loaded...');
            window.focus();
            if (document.activeElement) {
              document.activeElement.blur();
            }
            document.addEventListener('keydown', ()=>{
                console.log('keydown event loaded...');
                alert('Key down')
            });
        });
```

have fun :)

Comment: Thanks, that works. `window.focus();` does not seem necessary tho